# how do i display how many digits the number has?

Tags: c#, while-loop

Currently very new to C# and coding , so i will be more than happy if someone will explain me how to display how many digits the number has. For example the number 12345 has 5 digits.the main theme in the class is while loops so the answer probably need to contain while loop.TY

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code that you can share that shows where you are stuck?

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking folks here to do your homework for you. I can see a couple of answers here but I'd encourage you to attempt your own solution first before asking and share what you've tried so we can help when you get stuck. This is more a mathematical question than a programming question though. Ask yourself how you would mathematically determine the number of digits in any number. Then the equivalent program code should be more obvious.

Comment: I agree with @StevePalmer, you should be working this stuff out. Your professor usually doesn't assign work without giving you a base to work off of.

Comment: if you want to become a good programmer see if you can find several ways of doing this (some good methods are in various answers). For extra credit make your code work in the case where the answer for -1 is 1 or 2 (ie have a switch - run time or compile time)

Comment: Should leading zeroes be counted, or not?  Is the number an integer?  Can it have a sign?   You'll have to consider these questions.   E.g., the answer involving Math.Abs() below won't work on decimal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use this

```
Math.Abs(myint).ToString().Length
```

and if you absolutely must use a while loop then

```
number = Math.Abs(number);
int length = 1;
while ((number /= 10) >= 1)
   length++;
```

To test [code](http://goo.gl/uWazFx)

Comment: I agree, dasblinkenlight, that these are important tests, but the methods are good in principle.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The two were both tested with the cases you provided.

Comment: That's much better :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Trim().Replace("-","").Length
```

so if you have a number you should make it a string first using `ToString()`

The Length returns the number of characters that you hold within your string minus your white spaces (Because of the `Trim()`),i don't see why you would want to use the while loop in the first place.

Edit : if you have a minus number the `.Replace()` will take care of that.

Comment: what should the answer be for -1 anyway. It has one digit, but it takes 2 chars to display. We dont know the requirement